# "Restrictive clause with indefinite article vs definite article"

Tags: grammar

1) A person who is poor  has to face a lot of problems in daily life.

2) The person who is poor has to face a lot of problems in daily life.

As far as rules are concerned, we use "definite article " creating restrictive clause . What's the problem with "Indefinite article ". It's always incorrect to use indefinite article? Sentence number (1) incorrect? Please explain.

Comment: Is there an appositive in your sentences?

Comment: #P.E. Dant I edited my post please answer now.

Comment: What rule are you referring to here? Can you expand your question a little? (Either sentence might be perfectly correct in this case.)

Comment: I am referring to restrective clause.Can you give some examples of restrective clauses with "Indefinite articles"?

Comment: "I have a math problem that I just cannot solve"; "I found a key that was dropped on the ground"; "I know a nice place where we can relax".

Comment: In the 2nd sentence, "who is poor" doesn't limit the possible meaning of a preceding subject "the person" but gives additional information about it -- so it is a non-restrictive clause and should be surrounded by commas.

Comment: @Rompey Surely it distinguishes a poor person from some other kind of person and hence is restrictive.

Comment: @BillJ - Even without context? How can we be sure that the PO means any poor person, not the one that was mentioned before or one from several ones already mentioned?

Comment: @Rompey The salient interpretation is that when using "the" like that, we are referring to any person, cf. "Any person who is poor has to face ...", and also cf. "the person who steals my possessions steals trash".

Answer (score 1):

An indefinite article before a singular countable noun generalizes its context;

> A person (in general) who is poor has to face a lot of problems in daily life.

A definite article **the** before a singular countable noun specifies its context;

> The person (who I am talking about) who (also) is poor has to face a lot of problems in daily life.

P.S. A singular countable noun always comes after a determiner, a possessive, or so; eg;

> Person who is poor has to face a lot of problems in daily life. -- Incorrect

[for more](https://cegepenglish.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202713955-Generalizations-Non-Specific-References-When-to-Use-a-the-or-plural-s-)